# MySQL Failing to Replace in Parent Table due to Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables.

- **TableA** has id (pk) and name (varchar). - parent
- **TableB** has id (fk to TableA) and name (varchar). - child
- **TableC** has id (fk to TableA) and name (varchar). - child

All 3 tables have records for id's 1,2 and 3.

I have a new data set with data for records for id's 2,3,4,5 and 6. If i try to run `REPLACE` on **TableA**, then i run into foreign key constraint error. I cannot replace into the children first; it has to be the parent.

The only solution i could find was to turn off the FK Check, run the replace and then turn on the FK Check.

Is there a better or more elegant solution to this issue? I feel like i'm stuck in a catch 22. Thanks.

Comment: Use `UPDATE` instead of `REPLACE`. `REPLACE` works by deleting the old row and inserting the new row, but deleting causes a foreign key error.

Comment: `UPDATE` doesn't insert new rows however. All i know is that i have a data set of let's say 500k records. I don't know which ones need to be `UPDATED` vs `INSERTED`.

Comment: Then use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Comment: Any good way of generating that with exporter or a cmd line tool? E.g. the exporter and mysql can both generate `INSERT` statements for a full table. Any way to have it generate the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`? Thanks.

Comment: I doubt it. Export usually assumes that it's loading into an empty table. Turning off FK checks may be the only easy solution.

Comment: *Any good way of generating that with exporter or a cmd line tool?* Create MySQL stored procedure (once) which imports raw new data into temporary table and performs according `INSERT .. ODKU`. Then generate script (each time when new data incomes) which saves new data into CSV-formatted text file accessible for MySQL and executes SP.

Comment: `INSERT` `ODKU` was actually a bad solution for anyone reading this thread, especially for MySQL; the overhead is too large when you're working with millions of records. The solution which performs the fastest and most elegant is to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` followed by bulk insertions.